# Which way should rotated pages face?

Tags: typesetting

I'm typesetting a book which includes a map. I rotated the map 90 degrees to fit it better to the page. Should the bottom of the map be on the spine side or the edge side of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the same norm is used globally as, for example, titling on the spine will be oriented differently depending on where the book is published.

In Canada, the bottom of the map would be at the edge of the page if it were on the right page. ETA: Typically, here, we would tilt our head to the left and read from bottom to top so my answer might differ if you have it on the left.

Make sure you also leave some space to accommodate for the binding if required.

Comment: Hmm, I can't say I disagree, but I'm also not convinced that there is just *one* logic to apply here. What if you have a rotated map (or image) on *both* sides of the spread? Would you then have to turn the book counter-clockwise to see the left page and clockwise to see the right? When it comes to for example a postcard where the front is portrait and the back is landscape I would normally make sure that you would have to turn the card clockwise after turning over. Like your right page. And then I'm thinking why not do the same with a left side?

Comment: I agree with Wolff. I'm really looking for the full conventional logic on this issue.

Comment: @PhineasGreene I think you would get a more thorough answer if you provided more context on your question. Actually, I assumed the map was on the right page but my answer might be different if it was on the left page. Typically, here, we would tilt our head to the left and read from bottom to top